# SQL Server SSIS Export as XML Error: Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x00. Line 1, position 40

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and SSIS.  I have an OLE DB source using the below SQL command to output to a flat file destination - that is configured to save as .XML

This is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @XMLOutput XML
DECLARE @XMLOutputChar nvarchar(max)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('myNameSpace' as ns)

SELECT @XMLOutput =
(
SELECT field1 
FROM   table1 
    FOR XML PATH('Testing'),TYPE, ROOT('TestingLoader'),ELEMENTS XSINIL
)

SET @XMLOutputChar = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@XMLOutput)

SELECT @XMLOutputChar AS XMLOutput
```

However, when I try to import the XML file into a 3rd party application I receive the error:

```
Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x00. Line 1, position 40.
```

Even if I try to view in MS Word I receive the error:

```
Unable to switch the encoding
```

Is this because I'm defining it as UTF-8 and nvarchar(max)?

Thanks.

Comment: Try opening the file in Notepad++ and view -> Show Symble -> All, and you can see if you have any characters

Comment: I cannot see any, no

Comment: What value/characters are on line 1?  at position 40?

Comment: @Brad Using OP's code and a temp table of my own creation, I get the `T` of the `TestingLoader` root node name. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TestingLoader...`

Comment: @Michael can you show us how you have the OLE DB Source, Data Flow, and Flat File Destination configured?

Comment: The title of your question says that you receive an error while exporting, but later on you say that you receive an error trying to import the file, so maybe have a look on what file "a 3rd party application" expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You re-posted this question on the Microsoft forum where I found it originally.
I already answered it there.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f85ebd77-e7cb-4073-81e7-77a2ed5ab425/sql-server-ssis-export-as-xml-error-name-cannot-begin-with-the-character-hexadecimal-value?forum=sqlxml

Comment: Why not rewriting the answer summary, since it is not recommended to write a **link only** answer